# angularjs issue on loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to call a service that is called chercherProfil and stock its result into a javascript array $scope.tagsByProfils but when i try to access it , the console is displaying the array as being undefined

here is a code snipped that can help you figure out my problem:

```
    $http.post(configuration.URL_REQUEST + '/chercherProfil', toSendCherche)
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $scope.profil = data;
                $http.post(configuration.URL_REQUEST + '/chercherTagsParProfil', {
                    idProfil: $scope.target
                }).success(function(data) {
                    $scope.tagsByProfils = data;
                    console.log(data);
                    $scope.tests = [];
                    console.log($scope.tagsByProfils[0].tag);
                    for (var p = 0; p < $scope.tagsByProfils.length; p++) {
                        $http.post(configuration.URL_REQUEST + '/getTagById', {
                            idTag: $scope.tagsByProfils[p].tag
                        }).success(function(data) {
                            $scope.resultFlag = data;
                            if ($scope.resultFlag.libelle.toUpperCase().match('^TITRE')) {
                                console.log($scope.tagsByProfils[p]);
                                $scope.tests[p] = '<p class="text-center" data-font="' + $scope.tagsByProfils[p].police + '" data-size="' + $scope.tagsByProfils[p].taille + '" data-lineheight="' + $scope.tagsByProfils[p].interligne + '" data-weight="' + $scope.tagsByProfils[p].interligne + '" data-coloration="' + $scope.tagsByProfils[p].coloration + '">' + $scope.resultFlag.libelle + ' : Ceci est un exemple de' + $scope.resultFlag.libelle + ' </p>';
                            } else {
                                $scope.tests[p] = '<p class="text-center" data-font="' + $scope.tagsByProfils[p].police + '" data-size="' + $scope.tagsByProfils[p].taille + '" data-lineheight="' + $scope.tagsByProfils[p].interligne + '" data-weight="' + $scope.tagsByProfils[p].interligne + '" data-coloration="' + $scope.tagsByProfils[p].coloration + '">' + $scope.resultFlag.libelle + ' : CnedAdapt est une application qui permet d\'adapter les documents. </p>';
                            }


                        });
                    };
});
```

Any ideas or feed backs may be welcome

Comment: A few things. First, it's probably not the best idea to be using the $http service inside a controller, I'd move that to a service. Also, I'd decouple your nested $http requests you have going. Make the request, cache the data, then make a separate request with that new data. Don't nest them.

Comment: Can you verify what you're getting back as "data"?  You mention the console shows the array as undefined for $scope.tagsByProfils, but didn't really say if you are actually getting data back from your ajax call.

Comment: @CraigSquire yes i am getting back data

Comment: I don't think there's enough info here.  At what point are you seeing the error?  Is it one of the lines in your posted code?  Are you using tagsByProfils in a template and trying to access it before it has been initialized?

Comment: Few other things : you should consider using promise instead of callback in your case to have a more readable code. And may be you have a special reason for using "post" request and not the "get" for a search ("chercher") ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it completly solve your problem, but think about protecting your for loop counter because your are using it in a closure way:

```
for (var p = 0; p < $scope.tagsByProfils.length; p++) {
   (function(p){
       $http.post(configuration.URL_REQUEST + '/getTagById', {
                        idTag: $scope.tagsByProfils[p].tag
       [...]

    })(p)
```